# use requirejs partially and include javascript manually sometimes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I started to use requirejs and all the tutorials I saw use requirejs to load jquery and backbone and all that js modules which other javascript files need.

I guess a project which uses requirejs have to convert all their javascript file to meet the required format of requirejs.
(using `require` and `define`)

Sometimes, I feel it's easier to work with simple `<script>` tag to include js file.

Are there simple way to mix the two methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually "OK" to mix the approaches (but there are some caveats<sup>1</sup>), although the overall effect will depend upon several factors. In any case, this is exactly what RequireJS ["shimming"](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) allows. You could also create a RequireJS module to shim an external JS file loaded via tags instead of using the configuration.

In my projects I normally load all the "usually suspects" *or* anything that must be run synchronously wrt inline page code (e.g. jQuery) via `<script>` elements and add shims as appropriate. (The latest jQuery versions already work with RequireJS/AMD, so this isn't required per-se.)

Then I use RequireJS modules for other code. As per below, since jQuery is shimmed (and loaded via `<script>`), then it can be include as a dependency in any relevant module.

---

<sup>1</sup> The *big* difference between RequireJS/AMD and `<script>` elements is that RequireJS/AMD is *asynchronous* while `<script>` elements are (usually) *synchronous*. Here are the basic rules:

1. `<script>` includes can use other `<script>` includes, as long as they are executed *after*.
2. A RequireJS module can depend upon a RequireJS model, or a shimmed `<script>` include.
3. A `<script>` include *cannot* use a RequireJS model unless it uses RequireJS.

Also note that, a script converted to a RequireJS module *can still be included* via a `<script>` element (with the caveat that the function is not guaranteed to run synchronously), which can aid with transitioning. Of course, this should likely be a transitional step as the whole project is moved to follow the RequireJS/AMD approach.

Answer (score -3):

Vanilla JavaScript should always work regardless of what libraries you include.

For instance, you can use all of these in your `<head>` section:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.9/minified/require.js"></script>
```

Just be sure to read the section called [RequireJS and jQuery](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html) to get the integration correct.

Comment: ah, what about the ones that uses jquery?

Comment: Include the jQuery library to use it. I mix jQuery and Vanilla JS all the time.

Comment: AH, do we have a CS downvoter that's afraid to cast their view?

Comment: I guess the down vote is because you're not answering the question. He's asking how to write HIS OWN script such that he can use them by either `<script src="MY_OWN_SCRIPT.js">` or `require(["MY_OWN_SCRIPT"],function(mine){})` without having to write it twice.